# Can a boundary between bounded and unbounded solutions of a differential equation have a shape of a fractal?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, fractals

Iterative maps (like $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c$, where $z\in  \mathbb{C}$, $z_0=c$) sometimes have a fractal-like boundary between bounded and unbounded sequences (Mandelbrot set). Are there differential equations that have a similar property of the fractal boundary between bounded and unbounded solutions?

I have tried to build the analogue of the Mandelbrot fractal with a differential equation,
$$z+z'+\frac{1}{2!} z''+\frac{1}{3!} z'''+ \frac{1}{4!}z''''=z^2+c$$ with initial conditions $z(0)=c$, $z'(0)=z^2+c-z$, $z''(0)=z'''(0)=0$. The result looks the following (color of each pixel corresponds to the time $t$ when $|z(t)|=100$ for the first time; Calculations were performed for $t<300$):

[image]

Even though the plot may seem to resemble Mandelbrot fractal, with a closer look the boundary appears fairly smooth:

[image]

Do all boundaries between bounded and unbounded solutions for differential equation look this simple (meaning, they are not fractals)?